# Proper way to watch HEVC on supported browser like Chromium

Tags: chromium, browser, codecs, hevc

I'm currently experiencing issues with HEVC playback on Jellyfin mediaplayer. I've tried almost everything to get it working but it doesn't seem to find the appropiate codecs or something.

My rig has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8109U CPU @ 3.00GHz, which is powerfull enough to watch 4k on VLC, but doesn't work on the browser. Jellyfin starts to transcode like crazy to x264, which causes allot of stuttering and cpu power on my NAS.

What can i do to get it working? I like to watch my 4k content on my browser. Jellyfin client also stutters.

Best regards

Comment: Why not use VLC?

Comment: Because i don't want to use a desktop application, when a have a full web interface with all information, actors, ratings, watched information, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Jellyfin writes:

> Jellyfin will use FFmpeg to convert the media to a format that the
> client can process

If your client is a browser, it does exactly what you observe: it recodes the stream, converting it to h264 in a mkv or mp4 container. This is a resource hog.

You might have a chance with Chromium 104 when launched with

`--enable-features=PlatformHEVCDecoderSupport`

argument. If that doesn't work, use VLC.

Since VLC supports HEVC natively, you could setup a VLC streaming server on your nas.

More infos [here](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/clients/codec-support.html)

Comment: I've already tried that, but it seems that it cannot find the codecs needed i guess.